# Google Maps API error message

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I am using Google maps API JavaScript v3 in my app. When I run the app locally the image I receive is clear and there are no grid lines through the map, however i have deployed it to my heroku app (http://vast-mesa-7271.herokuapp.com/contactus) and the map has black grid lines through it, the icon to jump into street view is missing off the second map. i do have this error message though

```
   Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type application/octet-stream:
```

I am curious to know whether this has anything to do with why I am getting inconsistencies or whether it is a heroku thing? I have found this explanation elsewhere

```
  This warning is telling you that your web server isn't configured to send the correct   MIME type meta data for PNG images. You should probably consult the administrator for your web server and ask them to set the correct MIME mapping
```

Is this correct?

Comment: Not sure if relevant but I've run into similar issues with Apache. You just need to change the MIME types that your server knows about. For apache this was done under `/etc/mime.types` but for rails I think it is under `config/initializers`. See this article for details about solving a related problem under rails: http://9elements.com/io/?p=306 You need to add the mapping `".png" => "image/png"`.

Comment: thanks ivan, i will have a look at this later today, will let you know how i get on

Comment: Any update on this? Did my suggestion help?

Comment: not working, im having trouble with getting the exact syntax correct